# Filter async with akka-stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is there an equivalent to the `mapAsync()` method, but for `filter`?

Here is an example using pseudo code:

```
val filter: T => Future[Boolean] = /.../

source.filter(filter).runWith(/.../)
       ^^^^^^
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct method of `Flow` or `Source` that has the capability you're looking for, but a combination of the available methods will get you what you want:

```
def asyncFilter[T](filter: T => Future[Boolean], parallelism : Int = 1)
                  (implicit ec : ExecutionContext) : Flow[T, T, _] =
  Flow[T].mapAsync(parallelism)(t => filter(t).map(_ -> t))
         .filter(_._1)
         .map(_._2)
```

Comment: looks like we need to construct a `(Boolean, T)` tuple as the output of the internal `map` stage, right?   
`Flow[T].mapAsync(parallelism)(t => filter(t).map(b -> (b, t))).filter(_._1).map(_._2)`

Comment: @jmcnulty the `_ -> t` does construct a tuple.  In your example you would want `.map(b => (b, t)`; the way I wrote it is the equivalent short hand.  Note: `->` create a tuple, `=>` creates a function.